# SQL Server Management Studio: Display executed date/time on the status bar

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012, ssms-2014

When I execute a SQL query (e.g., SELECT 1) in SSMS, I can see the time it took to execute in the status bar. I would like to know whether it is possible to configure SSMS to show the date time the query was executed at (for example: Executed DateTime: 2015-07-28 11:15:30, not bothered about the date/time format) on status bar or in messages tab?

Here is the bar I am talking about with the section of interest enclosed in green rectangles.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for something similar, and found that if you hit F4, you can get this info (and more) from the Properties Window.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Click on Options, click on Editor Tab and Status Bar, under Status Bar Content, for Display execution time, select End. This shows the time of day that the script completed.

This works but you won't see elapsed time unless you enable the client statistics, but that only shows after query executes. There would be no way to determine how long the query has been running.

I wish MS can have both options, elapsed and end time. Would make life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. Ways around this include:

- Do a SELECT GETDATE() at the start of the procedure.
- Include the query statistics in the output (you'll need to dig into other tabs to see the detail though...)
- Execute sp_who2 @spid and look for the last batch time on the job. (You may need to dig further into sys.dm_os_exec_requests)

I guess the best question I can ask is *why* are you looking to do this? Given that SSMS executes commands you request it do - you can just take note of the time yourself or log the start/stop time to a table.

Comment: I am little curious to know whether a query was executed or not when I logged into the server. Consider this scenario: I need to `RESEED` a table to its `MAX_ID + 1000` after restoring a production Database on a test server (this can be accessed by multiple users), when I logged into the server the `SQL` query was left open in the query window, but I wasn't sure if it was executed or not, so thought to check if there is a way. I can get around this with checking `IDENT_CURRENT` on the table, but was curious to know if there is a way. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You will need to to look at sp_who2 @spid in a seperate window in order to see if you've actually run the specified command. You can also check from the second window using DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@spid) to see the command text you submitted last.